# Current date in workbook cell's

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vbscript

I have a workbook report in which there are several sheets, every sheet is having a one common cell, in which there is current date & time.

But when the file is opened in the future it should not get change to the future date. it should remain the same which it was created.

`8/8/2017 8:52 AM IST` exact format of the cell.

In this above cell the date is changing every day as this is a report.

Is there any way when I open the file for generating the report date should get changed with the current date.

The file name is also having the date mentioned.

Comment: Have you tried "=TODAY()"?

Comment: No I haven't tried it, because when the previous day file is open then it will show the current day.

Comment: You may need to clarify your question. As it reads now, @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose 's comment will work. You stated: "Is there any way when i open the file the date should get changed with the current date." "=TODAY()" or if you want the time, "=NOW()" will change the cell to the current date and time.

Comment: When you say "But when the file is opened in the future it should not get change to the future date. it should remain the same which it was created." it sounds like the date is a formula and you don't want it to be. But when you say "Is there any way when I open the file for generating the report date should get changed with the current date." it sounds like you DO want to be a formula based on that day's current date.